# Bash find in current folder and #name# sub-folder recursively

Tags: bash, shell, find, command-line-interface

Tricky question for a bash noob like me, but i'm sure this this easier that it seems to me.
I'm currently using the find command as follows :

```
run "find #{current_release}/migration/ -name '*.sql'| sort -n | xargs  cat >#{current_release}/#{stamp}.sql"
```

in my capistrano recipe.

Problem is #{current_release}/migration/ contains subfolders, and I'd like the find command to include only one of these, depending on it's name (that I know, it's based on the target environment.

As a recap, folder structure is

```
Folder
|- sub1
|- sub2
```

and i'm trying to make a find specifying to recurse ONLY on sub1 for example. I'm sure this is possible, just couldn't find how.
Thanks.

Comment: Is `find #{current_release}/migration/sub1` not what you want?

Comment: No, I probably didn't explain myself well. The goal is to list AT ONCE all the files in current folder and specified subfolder but WITHOUT any other subfolder.

Comment: I updated my answer, hope it's what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply specify the directory you want as argument to find, e.g. `find #{current_release}/migration/sub1 ...`.

EDIT: As per your clarification, you should use the `-maxdepth` argument for `find`, to limit the recursion depth. So, for example, you can use `find firstdir firstdir/sub1 -maxdepth 1`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, didn't know about the maxdepth option !!

Comment: @pixelboy You can also use `-and -not -path` and specify the path you dont want `find` to search on.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to append that to your `find` invocation:

```
 find #{current_release}/migration/sub_you_want -name ...
```

Depending on how you make the determination of the sub-directory you want, you should be able to script that as well.

Comment: The goal is to FIND AT ONCE all the files in current folder and specified subfolder but WITHOUT any other subfolder.

Comment: Sorry - I missed the 'and current directory' portion of your question. @spatz has it, assuming you don't need to recurse in sub1.